# GET an SVG file as a string from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, svg

```
    $.get('/vectorimage.svg', function(svg){

        //returns undefined
        console.log(svg.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].innerHTML);

        //returns undefined
        console.log(svg.documentElement.innerHTML);

        //returns document
        console.log(svg);
    });
```

I want to get the response as a string plain and simple.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
$.get('/vectorimage.svg', function(svg){
    console.log( svg );
}, 'text');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    $.get('/vectorimage.svg', function(svg){
        console.log($(svg).html());
    });
```